# Why was there a goodwill mission in "Civil War" if Wakanda was always in shadows?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, black-panther-2018

I recently watched *Black Panther*, and in the end T'Challa announces he bought certain buildings on Oakland to turn them into the first Wakandan Outreach Centre. That's great.

But in *Civil War*, Wanda inadvertedly blows up what T'chaka later claims was a goodwill mission from "a country too long in shadows", implying there already was an effort by Wakanda to help other countries (e.g. Nigeria in this case), and thta Wakanda was going to come out by then.

This seems to contradict what T'Challa said in *Black Panther*, and the fact that by the time of the last film everyone, including the highly-informed Agent Ross and the committee they visit at the end, is convinced Wakanda is nothing but a thirld-world country of farmers and shepherds.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

The only option that makes sense to me is that Wakandans can go out and help the world, as long as they don't betray the country's secrets.

There are two examples of this as seen in *Black Panther*:

- N'Jobu, T'Challa's uncle, lives in the United States for presumably over a decade (judging by the age of his son), it's likely much of this time was spend providing honest aid to poor neighborhoods before he started selling vibranium to Klaue to finance revolutions.
- Nakia is working undercover to help free some kidnapped women before T'Challa drops in on her, later T'Challa asks her to stay in Wakanda and she refuses.

It's also mentioned later in the film that Wakanda has many undercover agents all over the world.

The main issue that comes up isn't that Wakandans aren't helping, but rather that they aren't making use of their massive technological and mineral resources to either help everyone in need or conquer the world (depending on who you ask).

So, if the Wakandans killed in *Civil War* always insisted that they came from a third-world country and didn't use any of their homeland's technology or vibranium to further their goals, then presumably Wakanda would see no problem with their humanitarian efforts.

It's also plausible that these Wakandans, like N'Jobu or Nakia, were working undercover. Possibly they were in Lagos for the same reason as the Avengers. After their highly publicized deaths, maybe 'they were aid workers, the Avengers need to be stopped' was the perfect cover story to shift the world's attention away from the secretive nation.

Comment: That makes sense. A well-thought answer. Still, one wonders what kind of humanitarian help an alleged third-world country of farmers, etc, might have been providing there.

Comment: @Gallifreyan maybe it was some sort of pan-African volunteer organization, something like the Peace Corps. Plus, it's the MCU; stranger things *have* happened.

Comment: Can't argue with that :D

Answer (score -1):

**"Black Panther"** made it clear that N'Jobu was in Oakland, California clearly as a spy, like other members of the War Dogs (Wakanda's intelligence operation) to collect information on the world at large in order to insure Wakanda's anonymity and safety.